Method 'Range of Object'_worksheet' failed error on VBA
I am having an issues with the above listed error message (method range of object worksheet failed).  Essentially what I am trying to accomplish is run a large set of goal seeks any time any one of a number of inputs across a worksheet is changed.  This is a model to back into supplier margins based on a target SRP price and varying costs and markups in each state.
I've included screenshots of the error.  After detailed testing, I've resolved that it's not because of a named range issue.  It's almost as if the macro is unable to process more than a certain number of inputCells.  Here's what I mean.  You see a working version first (with goal seeks for 4 states from AL, ID, IA, ME).  The second screenshot is an example of the non-working version, which adds another state (MI).  HOWEVER, if I, say, replace ME with MI leaving 4 states, the macro works again.  This is how I know it's not a named range issue and suspect it is something else.  I have 17 total states to calculate for so I need to add many more inputCells and corresponding strings below to goal seek.
What could be causing this error?
I'm relatively new to VBA, so in addition to helping me solve the error I'm open to ways to clean up the code as well and make it tidier.
Thanks in advance!
[working code example]
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim inputCells As Range
Set inputCells = Range("ControlTgtSRP, " & _
"AL_ADA, AL_Broker, AL_Freight, AL_NetProfit, AL_SRP, " & _
"ID_ADA , ID_Broker, ID_Freight, ID_NetProfit, ID_SRP, " & _
"IA_ADA , IA_Broker, IA_Freight, IA_NetProfit, IA_SRP, " & _
"ME_ADA , ME_Broker, ME_Freight, ME_NetProfit, ME_SRP")

If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), inputCells) Is Nothing Then

    Range("AL_SRP").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("ControlTgtSRP"), ChangingCell:=Range("AL_NetProfit")
    Range("ID_SRP").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("ControlTgtSRP"), ChangingCell:=Range("ID_NetProfit")
    Range("IA_SRP").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("ControlTgtSRP"), ChangingCell:=Range("IA_NetProfit")
    Range("ME_SRP").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("ControlTgtSRP"), ChangingCell:=Range("ME_NetProfit")


End If
End Sub

[non-working code example - only difference is adding in logic to goal seek for an additional state]
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim inputCells As Range
Set inputCells = Range("ControlTgtSRP, " & _
"AL_ADA, AL_Broker, AL_Freight, AL_NetProfit, AL_SRP, " & _
"ID_ADA , ID_Broker, ID_Freight, ID_NetProfit, ID_SRP, " & _
"IA_ADA , IA_Broker, IA_Freight, IA_NetProfit, IA_SRP, " & _
"ME_ADA , ME_Broker, ME_Freight, ME_NetProfit, ME_SRP, " & _
"MI_ADA , MI_Broker, MI_Freight, MI_NetProfit, MI_SRP")

If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), inputCells) Is Nothing Then

    Range("AL_SRP").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("ControlTgtSRP"), ChangingCell:=Range("AL_NetProfit")
    Range("ID_SRP").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("ControlTgtSRP"), ChangingCell:=Range("ID_NetProfit")
    Range("IA_SRP").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("ControlTgtSRP"), ChangingCell:=Range("IA_NetProfit")
    Range("ME_SRP").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("ControlTgtSRP"), ChangingCell:=Range("ME_NetProfit")
    Range("MI_SRP").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("ControlTgtSRP"), ChangingCell:=Range("MI_NetProfit")


End If
End Sub

See above.  Tested for named range issues (e.g. typos).  Is not the issue.  Appears to be something to do with asking the macro to calculate across too many inputCells?
I have reviewed a number of other similar questions already asked on the site but don't seem to be able to find one with the same issue causing the error.

When writing Range(rngString), the rngString cannot exceed 255 characters.
In your working example the string length is 228. In the failing example it is 282.
The simplest solution is to UNION two or more ranges, each with a string length less than 255 characters:
Set inputCells = Union( _
    Range("ControlTgtSRP, " & _
          "AL_ADA, AL_Broker, AL_Freight, AL_NetProfit, AL_SRP, " & _
          "ID_ADA , ID_Broker, ID_Freight, ID_NetProfit, ID_SRP"), _
    Range("IA_ADA , IA_Broker, IA_Freight, IA_NetProfit, IA_SRP, " & _
          "ME_ADA , ME_Broker, ME_Freight, ME_NetProfit, ME_SRP, " & _
          "MI_ADA , MI_Broker, MI_Freight, MI_NetProfit, MI_SRP"))

